# Network naming: no LDAP server detected or configured

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, ldap

I am trying connect existing oracle database of existing project using asp.net. I have direct access to the oracle database.But for now I have created a simple table in the existing live oracle server and I am trying to connect to that server by creating a simple registration page in asp.net.
I am totally new into oracle and its configuration. I need to know the steps to connect my current asp.net application (login page and registration page). I am not using anything else other than visual studio 10 and oracle server (same error after trying to connect on local oracle server 11g)

The error message/exception i am getting is "Network naming: No LDAP server detected or configured"

What I have tried?

I have changed the connection string in the back end i.e the xyz.aspx.cs file, i have not made any changed in the web.config file.

Comment: Add some information about your system. Operating system, Software and so on.

Comment: windows OS , Oracle server,  visual studio 10

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by copying my `ldap.ora` (and other config files) over to where `tns.ora` file sits by default as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954207/visual-studio-2015-add-connection-dialog-doesnt-give-ldap-as-connection-type):

> if I select tns as connection type in Add Connection dialog box that's
>   when I come to know about tns file's default location.

[image: tns default location]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with vs.net 2019.

Error when creating db. conn. in IDE: Network naming: no LDAP server detected or configured. I resolved it by removing LDAP from sqlnet.ora file, from NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH param.